# How do I enable stapler when printing?

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I'm trying to print a word document from excel.

This works except I need to enable the stapler for this print job.

My printer, a Xerox workcentre 5755, can put one or two staples in the top left corner.

Excel apparently can manage this, I do NOT need to go into printer driver properties to enable the stapling, I can enable that directly from File-Print page.

When I go to this page, below "Settings" there is a dropdown written "No Staples" with a stapler symbol.

If I click that, I get choice of "No Staples", "Staple Top Left" and "Two Staples on Top Left" as well as other choices that are greyed out.

I tried recording a macro to print with staple top left and duplex printing.

This is what it gave me.

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

This does neither stapling nor duplex printing.

I read multiple threads on the subject but they are all old and don't really answer the question since in all cases the asker needed to change driver settings in properties so that is not my case. I have a printer that exposes the stapler function to excel.

Still I had to resort to one of the answers I found and that is to use sendkeys, which is highly unreliable.

Here is what my code looks like.

```
Sub PrintChecklist()
    Dim myprinter As String
    Dim PrintersList() As String
    Dim printer_name As String
    Dim x As Long

    Dim wordapp As Word.Application
    Dim CBC As CommandBarControl

    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")


    wordapp.Documents.Open "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\pool3.doc"

    wordapp.Visible = True

    myprinter = Application.ActivePrinter

    wordapp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize

    PrintersList() = GetPrinterFullNames

    For x = 1 To UBound(PrintersList)
        If InStr(1, PrintersList(x), "MYPRINTERNAME", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then _
           printer_name = PrintersList(x)
    Next x

    wordapp.ActivePrinter = printer_name

    DoEvents

    wordapp.Application.Activate

    ' only works in only one word opened
    Dim lRet As Long

    lRet = FindWindow("OpusApp", vbNullString)
    SetForegroundWindow lRet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CBC = Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=752)
    On Error GoTo 0



    If Not CBC Is Nothing Then
        CBC.Execute
        DoEvents

        '~~> File --> Print
        SendKeys "%fp"
        Sleep 3000
        SendKeys "k"
        Sleep 100
        SendKeys "{DOWN}"
        Sleep 100
        SendKeys "~"
        Sleep 100
        SendKeys "%fp"
        Sleep 100
        Sleep 1000
        SendKeys "s"
        SendKeys "3-5,1-2"

        SendKeys "%fp"

        Sleep 1000
        SendKeys "d"
        SendKeys "{DOWN}"
        SendKeys "~"

        SendKeys "%fp"

        Sleep 2000
        SendKeys "p"
        SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"


    End If


    Sleep 5000

    wordapp.ActivePrinter = myprinter
    wordapp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges


End Sub
```

It works but if there is a delay or if the user touches anything in that 10 second span, then it all goes wrong very quickly.

Any advice welcomed !

Comment: As far as I know, this is a printer specific feature and windows does not provide any API to set it programmatically. You need to manipulate the printer window as you are doing it right now.

Comment: Strange, as you can see in this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/2qER9rO.jpg,  it seems that it is handled by excel.   I found another way to resolve this, though it is a bit of a kludge, it is still more reliable than sendkeys (which have had been using for months !) .    I went to another computer and shared the printer. I then added this printer to my computer so I now had a second copy of the printer. I named this printer "Checklistprinter"  and set the stapler to be permanently on.   Now it prints everytime and I no longer need "sleep 5000" !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has gotten attention but no official answer, here is how I have dealt with this.

My printer is a network printer, so I have added it a second time to my computer under a different name. I set the default for that printer to be "with top left staple"

Now if I want to print with a staple, I print to that printer name instead of the other.

A bit quirky but it works reliably